# R lordif Rmarkdown

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown

I tried to add a plot in a `rmarkdown` file from the plot-method in `lordif`.
Here is the simple example :

````
```{r}

library(lordif) 
data(Anxiety)

age.dif <- lordif(Anxiety[paste("R",1:29,sep="")],Anxiety$age)
plot.lordif(age.dif,labels=c("Younger","Older"),width=8,height=7,cex=0.8,lwd=1)

```
````

If you run the code on the console it produces multiple plots, however not in `rmarkdown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there exists `dev.new()` in the function `plot.lordif()` ! You can check it up with :

```
> as.list(body(plot.lordif))
```

and discover `dev.new()` right in the ninth part :

```
> body(plot.lordif)[[9]]

# if (sysname == "Windows") {
#     dev.new(width = width, height = height, record = TRUE)
# } else if (sysname == "Linux") {
#     dev.new(width = width, height = height)
#     par(ask = TRUE)
# } else {
#     dev.new(width = width, height = height)
# }
```

`dev.new()` prevents markdown from displaying your plots.
So just get rid of this part and override the function.

You can try to revise the function by adjusting the function body :

```
> body(plot.lordif)[[9]] <- NULL
```

---

To fulfill this in markdown, you can add a additional chunk and not show it in your document with `echo = FALSE`.

````
```{r echo = FALSE}
library(lordif)
body(plot.lordif)[[9]] <- NULL
```

```{r}
data(Anxiety)
age.dif <- lordif(Anxiety[paste("R",1:29,sep="")],Anxiety$age)
plot.lordif(age.dif,labels=c("Younger","Older"),width=8,height=7,cex=0.8,lwd=1)
```
````